# Using google maps API to show a unique marker instead of all markers

Tags: javascript, xml, api, geocoding

Here is the code I have been using to get information from a php created XML file and output the geolocation markers on a map.

```
//<![CDATA[

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4640, -4.9700),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("dbxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var blogs = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("blog");
    for (var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {
      var subject = blogs[i].getAttribute("subject");
      var content = blogs[i].getAttribute("content");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(blogs[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
          parseFloat(blogs[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
      var html = "<b>" + subject + "</b> <br/>" + content;
      var blog = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
      });
      bindInfoWindow(blog, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(blog, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(blog, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, blog);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
```

This is the the generated XML file name.
    dbxml.php

At the moment I can extract the geolocation data and display markers for each location.  What I am trying to do is only show the marker for the ID that is in the URL.

```
post.php?id=1
post.php?id=2
post.php?id=3
```

So say in the url it contained 'post.php?id=2' just now the map would still pull markers for all 3 instead of just the one with reference to 'id=2'

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the value of url parameter id (which you can do in PHP). I am assuming the id corresponds to the blog index. Replace your 'for loop' with the following single call:

```
var id=<?php $_GET['id']; ?>;
var subject = blogs[id].getAttribute("subject");
      var content = blogs[id].getAttribute("content");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(blogs[id].getAttribute("latitude")),
          parseFloat(blogs[id].getAttribute("longitude")));
      var html = "<b>" + subject + "</b> <br/>" + content;
      var blog = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
      });
      bindInfoWindow(blog, map, infoWindow, html);
```

Comment: I am just getting an empty box, the map isn't loading.  I see what you are doing though.

Comment: downloadUrl("dbxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var blogs = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("blog");
        var id=<?php $_GET['id']; ?>;
  var subject = blogs[id].getAttribute("subject");
  var content = blogs[id].getAttribute("content");
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(blogs[id].getAttribute("latitude")),
          parseFloat(blogs[id].getAttribute("longitude")));
      var html = "<b>" + subject + "</b> <br/>" + content;
      var blog = new google.maps.Marker({